# Iterating over map with typescript does not work

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have a Typescript Map with IDs as keys and booleans as values. I want to iterate over the map and check if at least one is true. I know it would be possible with forEach, but i want to exit the loop after the first was found.

This is my coding (according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Iterating_over_a_Map):

```
        private isOneSelected(): boolean {
            for (let [key, value] of this.selectionMap) {
                if (value) {
                   return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

But it is not entering the loop at all.
The compiled js file looks like this:

```
            SelectionController.prototype.isOneSelected = function () {
            for (var _i = 0, _a = this.selectionMap; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
                var _b = _a[_i], key = _b[0], value = _b[1];
                if (value) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
            };
```

I am compiling against ES6 and i am using the es6-shim typings:
tsconfig file:

```
[...]
"compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "rootDir": "./client",
    "outDir": ".tmp/client",
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs"
},
[...]
```

Thanks,

Tobias

Comment: What do you mean by *TypeScript map*? A  `Map` or an object like `[ [index: number]: number`? And which error do you get?

Comment: The map looks the following way: selectionMap: Map<String, boolean>;

Thats the problem. I do not get any errors. The map is just undefined for the loop and i does not enter (but a console.log or something outside the for loop works fine).

Answer (score 1):

`Map` does not have a `length` property, that's why the compiled version does not work. You could try `this.selectionMap.entries()` as it directly returns the `Iterable` of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to check if at least one is true, you can use

```
this.selectionMap.filter(i=>i.key == true).length >= 1 ;
```

Comment: Yes, but that way i iterate over the whole map. I could do that with a forEach also. But i want to stop after the first "true" for performance reasons.